# Test AR Core without a hardware camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

We are currently developing an AR app for Android and iOS using Unity. And we are wondering if it is possible to test AR Core functionalities without any hardware camera. Only using something like a virtual environment or feeding it a pre recorded video? We want the ability to test stuff in a simulator or emulator first since we are working remotely and everyone doesn't have compatible devices.

Unity have a Simulated environment for testing AR behaviors but it is only limited to the editor and doesn't work on a built app.